# onclick event for all inputs in a form?

Tags: jquery, input, onclick, fade

DANG IT. There is no `fade()` - answer found.

I want to have it so that whenever someone clicks on a form input, a div fades away.

```
    $( '#form_id' ).find( 'input' ).click(function() {

        $( '#div_to_fade_away' ).fade();

    });
```

Why wouldn't that work? 
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088319/select-all-inputs-of-a-given-form-in-jquery). Appears to work for this use?

Comment: How would you know which `div` to fade out?

Comment: `$( '#div_to_fade_away' )` - Wouldn't that select it?

Comment: That would select it, yes. But if this is a click-handler for all inputs, then that will select only one `div`, which will be hidden after the first handler is called.

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple page, I want all the inputs on the page to have this `div` to be hidden. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [`fadeOut()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method  instead of `.fade()`, and make sure the DOM is loaded.

```
$(function() {
    $( '#form_id' ).find( 'input' ).click(function() {

        $( '#div_to_fade_away' ).fadeOut();

    });
});
```

Wrapping your code with `$(function() { /* your code */ });` is a shortcut for calling jQuery's [`ready()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method.

Comment: Yeah, it's already in a `ready()` function. That fixed it. I didn't even think of that as I thought the `.click()` syntax was wrong.

Comment: @Phil: Yeah the `.click()` is fine, but be aware *every* `<input>` element it finds will fadeOut the same `div_to_fade_away` element (if visible). That's what @David Thomas was referring to in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

While I think there's the more to this question than you stated, the reason that your posted jQuery doesn't work is that there is no `fade()` method. You can, however, use [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).