# selecting inputs and textareas using jquery .submit function

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have multiple forms that are exactly the same on one page. I want to be able to edit and submit each form individually (i will be using the $.ajax function).

jQuery is still very confusing for me as I have no previous knowledge of javascript. I have successfully used it to build many forms and make my website easier to use, but I have ran into a wall with the current script I'm building.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".savenpcf").submit(function(form) {
        var npcid = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
        var name = ;
        alert(npcid +" "+ name);
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Each form has the same class (savenpcf) and a different ID. I need to get the id of the form (already achieved this) and the values of inputs and textarea's inside this form for submission.

I am able to get the id of the form with the closest() function, but I have tried several ways to get the values of inputs and textareas with nothing working. name always shows up as undefined in the alert. What would be the best method for me to get about 6 inputs and 2 textareas from the form?

Comment: Can you please post your HTML code?

Comment: `<form class="savenpcf" id="php_generates_id_here" name="same_as_id">
<input type="text" id="n_name" name="n_name" value="blabla">
<input type="text" id="n_power" name="n_power" value="blabla">
<input type="text" id="n_dropcash" name="n_dropcash" value="blabla">
<input type="text" id="n_dropitems" name="n_dropitems" value="blabla">
<textarea id="n_description" name="n_description">blabla</textarea>
<textarea id="n_speech" name="n_speech">blabla</textarea>
</form>`

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088319/select-all-inputs-of-a-given-form-in-jquery?

Comment: If you want to serialize the values of the form, since you already have the id of the form, I think you can do something like this: `$('#formId').serialize();`

Comment: serialize was the perfect solution! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i read your question right.. You're trying to get 2 textboxes and a textarea input within a form?

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".savenpcf").submit(function(form) {
        var $myForm = $(this).closest('form'); 
        var npcid = $myForm.attr('id');
        var textbox1 = $('input:eq(0)', $myForm).val();
        var textbox2 = $('input:eq(1)', $myForm).val();
        var textArea = $('textarea', $myForm).val();
        alert(npcid +" "+ textbox1 +" "+ textbox2 +" "+ textArea);
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```